# How to do error handling in Stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, sap-ase

I am using Sybase ASE 12.5 at the moment. I have a code below:

```
create procedure test_launcher_fail_wrapper
as
begin

   select convert(numeric(2),1234345)

   if @@error != 0
   begin
      select "SP failed to execute"
      return 1
   end

end
```

Here, I am trying to convert a very large value/amount (1234345) to Numeric size 2. Which is not possible and it generates error.

Questions:

1. Is having @@error useful here? I ran this SP and it never went into
   error handling
2. How to error handle these kind of scenarios?

Comment: Why the close votes. Its a very good and definite question with hopefully some interesting answers. SQL procedures are programs and error handling is a known problem area.

Comment: Belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: forgive my ignorance. But if this question belongs to different forum than can the Admin move it. Don't want to cross post.

Comment: its not within a try and catch block?

Comment: Meet - the question can be migrated.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Can you please move the question.

Answer (score 0):

I treat error handling in procs similarly to error handling in applications -- if there's an opportunity for you to contribute some actual value by handling the error, then by all means, do so, but if you can't really do anything to help, then you're better off just letting it go.

As an example of adding value, I've got one or two procs that add contextual information in the error message, like a list of ID values that conflict with an update operation.  In this particular case, I know that the upstream consumer of the proc will log this error, and the text will be available to an operator who will find this information valuable when debugging the problem.  I also know that while this condition is a real error, it's been known to happen from time-to-time, and the effort to format the error is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Does this catch your error?

```
create procedure test_launcher_fail_wrapper
as
begin

  declare @database_err int

  set @database_err = 0

  select convert(numeric(2),1234345)

  set @database_err = @@error

  if @database_err <> 0
  begin
    PRINT  'SP failed to execute'
    return 1
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

[@@error](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.pubs.iqerrs/concepts/con_syberror.html) is the way to go but beware since:

> Every Transact-SQL statement, including print statements and if tests, resets @@error, so the status check must immediately follow the batch for which success is in question.

As for a suggestion on how to handle error management in similar scenarios, have you considered using *[raiserror](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X60573.htm)* ?

An example:

```
create procedure proc1 as
begin
    select convert(numeric(2),1234345)
    if @@error <> 0
    begin
        raiserror 20001 "Error during convert in proc1"
        return 1
    end
end
```